# Turnkey user registration

Tags: django

Newbie to Django.  I am amazed with the admin panel.  Could anyone recommend a user registration system that I can layer onto just as easy?  Preferable one with view files included.

Answer (score 1):

Django is not a cms like wordpress where you just plugin stuff. However it is very easy to create an auth routine.. Just read the documentation, it's pretty essential to understand these docs to really get into the django business: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/

The examples on that page will give you a headstart:

Create a login and registration form view somewhere, then create an url pointing to this view (form action) and you'll have a (very) basic setup already

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label=_("E-Mail"))
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_("Repeat password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_("First name"))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_("Last name"))
    phone_number = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_("Phone number"))

    return signup_form

def sign_up(request):
    """
    View for signing up a customer
    """
    signup_form = customer_forms.SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if signup_form.is_valid():
        create_user_and_login(request)
        return #somewhere
    else:
        return #error handling

def create_user_and_login(request):
    ## Retrieve User data from form
    email = request.POST["email"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    first_name = request.POST["first_name"]
    last_name = request.POST["last_name"]
    ## Create a new user
    new_user = User()
    new_user.email = email
    new_user.username = email
    new_user.set_password(password)
    new_user.first_name = first_name
    new_user.last_name = last_name
    new_user.save()



from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

Ofcourse the form still needs cleaning (see django docs) Never trust user input..